# How to prove or disprove the following statement?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

How to prove or disprove the following statement:

"If random variables X and Y are independent, AND if random variables Y and Z are independent, then X and Z are independent."

I tried to use Bayes Rule to prove it but it doesn't work. I think it might actually be wrong... but I just cannot think about an example...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is an example of

$P(X)P(Y)=P(X\cap Y)$

$P(Y)P(Z)=P(Y\cap Z)$

$P(X)P(Z)\neq P(X\cap Z)$

Consider six mutually exclusive events {$s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4,s_5,s_6$} each with probability $1\over6$ (for example a dice)

Let

$X=\{s_1,s_2,s_5\}$ (any one of them happening)

$Y=\{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4\}$

$Z=\{s_1,s_2,s_6\}$

Then

$P(X)P(Y)=P(X\cap Y)={1\over3}$

$P(Y)P(Z)=P(Y\cap Z)={1\over3}$

$P(X)P(Z)={1\over4}\neq P(X\cap Z)={1\over3}$

Answer (score 2):

Another counter e.g.  take $X$ and $Y$ to be any two independent events, and let $Z$ be the same as $X$.